# c# read Azure table WAWSAppLogTableXXX

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I read the logs in the Azure table WAWSAppLogTableXXX that get saved with a website's diagnostics?

I guess I'm asking for the format of the columns... Particularly the PartitionKey.
But it'd be nice to see a page describing the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/ - "How to: Understand diagnostics logs" section has some details on this.